# 8 Register Machine with 4 2-operand instructions in 8-bit format

Tags: instruction-set, microprocessors

I'm studying Microprocessors and interfacing at uni and I've come across a very difficult question to get my head around.

"Can you design an 8-bit instruction format that cal allow 4 2-operand instructions for a machine with 8 registers"

I'm not 100% sure what it's asking, a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Note: The course is based around learning assembler on an AVR board (if it helps).

Comment: You need to find a way to encode (1) four instructions, (2) a register operand, (3) a second register operand. You have eight bits to work with. Go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's basically asking whether you can encode any of four different instructions, each with two register operands, into 8 bits (per instruction).

The answer would be yes. Simply count the number of possible operations: 4 instructions * 8 possible first registers * 8 possible second registers = 256; you can represent 256 possible values with 8 bits, so it must be possible to encode each of the 256 possible operations as a single 8-bit value.